# Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_100_CI_AS_KS_WS" in UNION ALL operator

Tags: sql-server

i have to databases one of these database is in my server and another one is in another server that i have just read access to it just can select data from tables.

now i have made 2 views, first view is from my data base and it's name is "qryTransmittals_Lines_with_CT_CS"

and second view gets it,s data from other server and other database is (qryTqLines)

now i want to union all data from both queries but i got error:

```
    Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" 
   and "Arabic_100_CI_AS_KS_WS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT 
 statement column 8.



  SELECT qryTqLines.*
 FROM qryTqLines

 UNION ALL

 SELECT qryTransmittals_Lines_with_CT_CS.*
 FROM qryTransmittals_Lines_with_CT_CS;
```

i checked collation of my table in my server is (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) and about another table i do not have access to modify design of table.

please help how i can solve my problem.

Comment: check here also my be help http://www.ashishblog.com/how-to-resolve-the-collation-conflict-and-how-to-check-collate-in-sql-server/

Comment: thanks, i read the link and my problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was provided link and OP solved his problem, so posting some code from provided link for future readers

Have to make both column with same Collate so we can compare.
1a. here we change collate of search.cat_id to collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from Latin1_General_CI_AS

```
SELECT     search.*
FROM         categories INNER JOIN search 
ON categories.cid  = search.cat_id collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

OR
1b. here we change collate of categories.cid to Latin1_General_CI_AS from collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

```
SELECT     search.*
FROM         categories INNER JOIN search 
ON categories.cid collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = search.cat_id
```

reference link

http://www.ashishblog.com/how-to-resolve-the-collation-conflict-and-how-to-check-collate-in-sql-server/